# Is there a word for "be popular for a time"?

Tags: word-request

Something had been popular for a period of time. How do I describe it?

Comment: Terms to look up in a thesaurus:  fad, trendy, hot, passé, dated, has-been.

Comment: @Jasper, Yes, I think "fad" is what I seek for. I think I have come across it serval times. And I just remembered its Chinese translation and forgot the word :)

Comment: **Fad** was the first thing that came to my mind when I saw your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways to say this.

> It's all the rage right now.

That implies it extremely popular right now.

> It's the current fad.

That's what's popular right now.

If you're speaking about the past I'd say

> It was the trend at the time to wear fur boots.